# How to delete an entry in a dependent entity?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have a principal entity `AppUser` and a dependent entity `Account`.

The following code shows a one-to-many relationship between them:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; } = new List<Account>();
}

public class Account
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public AppUser User { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

My `OnModelCreating` method looks like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.Entity<Account>()
        .HasOne(x => x.User)
        .WithMany(u => u.Accounts)
        .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.UserId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

Now if I have a `AppUser` object and want to remove one of its accounts like

```
user.Accounts.Remove(account);
```

This only removes the foreign key reference in that account entry. How can I make sure it fully deletes the entry in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `Remove` on the corresponding `DbSet` (assuming names of variable and the property):

```cs
_context.Accounts.Remove(account);
```

Also possibly you can consider marking the parent entity as required (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#required-and-optional-relationships) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#required-and-optional-properties)):

```cs
builder.Entity<Account>()
    .HasOne(x => x.User)
    .WithMany(u => u.Accounts)
    .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.UserId)
    .IsRequired(true)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```